# conexion de python a oracle

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

alguien sabrá como hacer la conexión de python a oracle ya que intente hacerla con

> import cx_Oracle

pero me salio el siguiente error

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot
>   be loaded: "The specified module could not be found". See
>   https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help

espero me puedan ayudar. 
saludos!

Comment: Es evidente que no tienes instalado el cliente de oracle (OCI).

Comment: @Memo que sistema operativo estas usando

Comment: windows 7 @RaulCacacho

Answer (score 1):

Actualización 2023:
El módulo cx_Oracle estuvo disponible hasta Python 3.10 y ya no tiene mantenimiento ni futuras versiones. [Ver anuncio](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/628).

El desarrollo de cx_Oracle ha sido renombrado a **python-oracledb**, y está disponible desde Python 3.7 o superior. Ver [Documentación](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/introduction.html).

Para instalar: `python -m pip install oracledb`

Para bases de datos antiguas (10, 11) o funcionalidad avanzada, habilitar "[thick mode](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html)" el cual usa Oracle InstantClient. Para ello, previamente [descargar Oracle InstantClient](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html), descomprimir y (opcional, pero recomendado) agregar la ruta a variable de entorno PATH de sistema. Si no se agrega a la variable de entorno, especificar la ruta en `oracledb.init_oracle_client(r"ruta/de/InstaClient")`

En el script de Python:

```py
import oracledb

oracledb.init_oracle_client() # <-- Thick mode
connection = oracledb.connect(user="el_user", password="el_passw", dsn="ip_server/xe")
# cambiar "xe" por el nombre de su servicio o instancia
# ...
cursor = connection.cursor()
# ...
```

Si no funciona, y/o desea especificar el **puerto**, **tnsnames.ora**..., ver [otras opciones de conexión](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Como hecho mi mini receta es para window 7 de 64 bits es

1. Se descarga Python 2.7 64 bit para Windows, [Python](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/python-2.7.amd64.msi)
2. Se descarga el módulo de conexión de Python a Oracle, [Driver](https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/c/cx_Oracle/cx_Oracle-5.2-11g.win-amd64-py2.7.exe#md5=e606259cfe6733e9f941ab2251c1f0bd)
3. Puedes probar con el siguiente codigo cambiando por tus valores

   ```
   import cx_Oracle
   conn_str='HR/HR@127.0.0.1:1521/XE'
   db_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
   cursor = db_conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM countries')
   registros = cursor.fetchall()
   for r in registros:
   print str(r)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yo he implementado el siguiente script muchas veces y siempre me ha funcionado. Previo debes descargar el módulo de conexión de Python a Oracle.

```
import cx_Oracle
ip = '10.8.8.8' #ip
port = 46  #port
SID = 'database'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'password', dsn_tns)
```